# Prove that for all $n \in \mathbb N$ the quotient of $\frac{3^{2^n}}{2^n}$ is an even number.

Tags: number-theory

Prove that for all $n \in \mathbb N$  the quotient of
$$\frac{3^{2^n}}{2^n}$$
is an even number. Maybe we have to check a more general case, namely $\displaystyle\frac{3^k}{k}$. What would you do here? Thanks!

Comment: You mean that $\lfloor 3^{2^n}/2^n\rfloor$ is an even integer, right?

Comment: @Peter Tamaroff: I just wrote it the way it's written in my textbook. Sure.

Comment: Try to write that number as $(3^k+1)/2^n$

Comment: Now that there are two answers - may I assume that the real question was to show that $\frac{3^{2^n}-1}{2^n}$ is even?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** 
$$3^{2^n}-1^{2^n}=(3^{2^{n-1}}+1^{2^{n-1}})(3^{2^{n-1}}-1^{2^{n-1}}).$$
Continue.

Comment: nice and simple :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From Euler's theorem, $3^{2^{n-1}} \equiv 1 \pmod {2^n}$

Hence, $$3^{2^{n-1}} = M2^n + 1 \implies 3^{2^n} = \left(3^{2^{n-1}} \right)^2 = \left(M2^n + 1 \right)^2 = 2^n \left( M^2 2^n + 2M\right) + 1$$

Hence, $$\dfrac{3^{2^n}}{2^n} = 2 M \left(2^{n-1} M + 1 \right) + \dfrac1{2^n}$$